# How to create HTML5/CSS/JavaScript project with Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: html, css, aptana

I created some project with Aptana Studio 3 (ex: ruby, rail, php, ...) but all of them have only one element, it is "Connections". I cannot find out HTML file on menu, so I create new file with extension is html but it doesn't include template, it's blank. I don't know I did right way or not and I hope someone can help me. Thanks !

http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3

Comment: I looked at Aptana for HTML5, CSS, and JS development and I found it unsuitable.  I would suggest something like Notepad++ or Textmate.

Comment: Jason, any rationale for that?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the project template feature:

1. Select File > New > Web Project;
2. Type a name for the project and select Next;
3. You should see multiple templates to choose from.

To use built-in file templates, right-click on the project or folder and select New From Template > file type > some Template.

To contribute your own project or file templates, you could read on [Creating a New Template](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Creating+a+new+template).